# Cox regression using inverse probability weight for both categorical and continuous exposures

Tags: r, cox-model

I would like to use a Cox regression model with time-varying covariates and time-varying exposure using a standardized inverse probability weight (IPW).

My exposure can be continuous (exp_continuous) and categorical(exp_quartiles). Q1: For different types of exposures, should I estimate two IPWs and fit two Cox models with two accordingly weights to evaluate the effects of two types of exposure? Or let's say I only estimated IPW when I chose exposure as the continuous type and then I used the IPW to fit two Cox models for the effects of continuous and categorical exposures, respectively. Is it appropriate?

Q2:Another question is that, when I calculated the IPW, can I still adjust for covariates in the Cox model along with weights?

For example, My code is shown below:

```
temp <- ipwtm(exposure =exp_continuous, family = "gaussian",  
             corstr = "exchangeable",
          trunc = 0.05,  
          numerator = ~ sex, 
          denominator = ~  age+ sex+ as.factor(drink) + 
                                as.factor(smoke) ,
          id = id, 
          timevar =tstop,
          type = "all",
          data = df)
```

Should my Cox model be like?

```
model <-coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ exp_continuous + age + 
                   sex + as.factor(drink) + as.factor(smoke),
    data    = df,
    weights = temp$weights.trunc,  
    ties    = c("efron", "breslow", "exact")[1])
```

or

```
 model <-coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ exp_continuous+sex,
    data    = df,
    weights = temp$weights.trunc,  
    ties    = c("efron", "breslow", "exact")[1])
```

Hope someone can answer my questions!

Comment: Is it really necessary to use a high-variance weighted method here?